# Custom RecyclerClickListener not working properly for multiple onClicks

Tags: android, onclicklistener, onitemclicklistener, android-recyclerview

I have a Recyclerview with custom onClickListener within it. now i am able to go next page when clicking on the whole recyclerview item. How will i make seperate click for image , text and checkbox.

My Current code is as follows:

Recycler class

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors.HomeRecyclerDetailActivity;
import com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors.R;
import com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors.projectdatabase.HomeManager;
import com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors.projectdatabase.HomeData;
import com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors.projectdatabase.RecyclerClickListener;
import com.kogitune.activity_transition.ActivityTransitionLauncher;

public class RecyclerTab1 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_tab1_recycler, container, false);
        RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.home_recyclerview);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
        rv.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true); // to improve performance
        rv.setAdapter(new HomeManager()); // the projectdatabase manager is assigner to the RV

        rv.addOnItemTouchListener( // and the click is handled
                new RecyclerClickListener(getContext(), new RecyclerClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), HomeRecyclerDetailActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra(HomeRecyclerDetailActivity.ID, HomeData.PROJECTS[position].getId());
                        ActivityTransitionLauncher.with(getActivity()).from(view).launch(intent);
                    }
                }));
        return v;
    }
}
```

Recycler Adapter

```
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors.R;


public class HomeManager extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeManager.RecyclerViewHolder> {

    public static class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView mProjectName, mProjectCity, mProjectType;
        ImageView mImage;
        CheckBox mCheck;
        RelativeLayout mProjectStatus;

        RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mProjectName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.PROJECT_name);
            mProjectCity = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.PROJECT_city);
            mProjectType = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.PROJECT_type);
            mImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.PROJECT_image);
            mCheck = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.PROJECT_fav);
            mProjectStatus = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new RecyclerViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        // get the single element from the main array

        final HomeData projects = HomeData.PROJECTS[i];
        // Set the values
        viewHolder.mProjectName.setText(projects.get(HomeData.Field.NAME));
        viewHolder.mProjectCity.setText(projects.get(HomeData.Field.CITY));
        viewHolder.mProjectType.setText(projects.get(HomeData.Field.TYPE));
        viewHolder.mImage.setImageResource(projects.geti(HomeData.Field.IMAGE));

  }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return HomeData.PROJECTS.length;
    }


}
```

Custom RecyclerClickListener

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;


public class RecyclerClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

    private OnItemClickListener mOnClickListener;
    GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }

    public RecyclerClickListener(Context context, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mOnClickListener = listener;
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
        View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (childView != null && mOnClickListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            mOnClickListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildPosition(childView));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create your own listener and pass it into `HomeManager`. Then in onBindViewHolder set onClickListeners for each element you want and in onClick call the proper method in listener.

Comment: but by this method how can i trigger the onClick according to the Recyclerview item..?? Can u please give me an example.

Comment: Just set a normal OnClickListener, nothing special.

Comment: Yes I did it. But click triggers only when I long press on any items such as text , check box. Why its like that ?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you without code.Can you show it?

Comment: I added this code to onBindViewHolder '  viewHolder.mCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(v, "Clicked", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                snackbar.show();
            }
        });  '

Comment: Did you removed your listener with onInterceptTouchEvent?

Comment: No. i didnt. should i remove it.?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97306/discussion-between-kaerdan-and-rubin-nellikunnathu).